# Avalonedit how to get the top visible line

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, avalonedit

In Avalonedit, how do I get the line number of the very top line that is visible to the user?

I believe I'm supposed to make some use out of VisualLines but it isn't helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GetDocumentLineByVisualTop`:

```
int firstLine = textView.GetDocumentLineByVisualTop(textView.ScrollOffset.Y).LineNumber;
```

`textView.VisualLines[0].FirstDocumentLine.LineNumber` would work as well, but you have to be careful there - the visual lines collection can be invalid if a redraw was requested but not performed yet (see `VisualLinesValid`/`EnsureVisualLines()`).

Comment: to clarify; `GetDocumentLineByVisualTop` can be found at `textEditor.TextArea.TextView.GetDocumentLineByVisualTop`